# Как добавить возможность указывать с помощью интерфейса схемами базы данных?

Tags: java, struts

Не могу разобраться как добавить возможность указывать с помощью интерфейса схемами базы данных? 
Вот такое задание поступило.

> Нужно добавить возможность указывать с помощью интерфейса схемами базы данных, а также найти ошибку и исправить генерацию кода `ValueObjects` (и всего другого кода, который на этот `ValueObject` полагается) таким образом, чтобы если тип поля в базе `NUMERIC(x,y)`, то чтобы генерировался не `Long`, а `BigDecimal`.